# React Redux Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, react-redux

I want to entegrate realtime chat to my exist react-redux project.But it give error:
    `MessageList.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` 
   **There is two components MessageList.js ve MessageForm.js**
Message form for sending message and message list is list component

**Here is MessageList.js component code**

```
import React from 'react';
import MessageForm from 'components/chat/MessageForm';
import { addMessage, deleteMessage } from 'actions/Chatactions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const MessageList = ({messageList, dispatch}) => (

  <div>
    <h1>Mesajlar</h1>
    <MessageForm onChange={e => {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
        dispatch(addMessage(e.target.value))
        e.target.value = ''
}
}}/>
{messageList.map((messageForm, index) => <p key={index}>{messageForm} <button onClick={e => {
    dispatch(deleteMessage(index))
}}>X</button></p>)}
</div>

)

function mapStateToProps(messageList) {
    return {
        messageList
        }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MessageList)
export default MessageList;
```

and here is **Here is MessageForm.js component code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const MessageForm = ({onChange}) => (
  <div>
    <h3>New</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your message here" onKeyUp={onChange}/>
  </div>
)

export default MessageForm
```

and here is my action

```
export function addMessage(MessageForm){
    return {
        type: 'addMessage',
        MessageForm
        }
}

export function deleteMessage(index){
    return {
        type: 'deleteMessage',
        index
        }
}
```

and here is my reducer(MessageList.js)

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'

export default (state = Immutable.List(), action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case 'addMessage':
return state.unshift(action.MessageForm)
    case 'deleteMessage':
    return state.filter((MessageForm, index) => index !== action.index)
    default:
return state
}
}
```

and this is my store(store.js is same path with index.html)

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import MessageList from './reducers/MessageList'
export default createStore(MessageList)
```

Comment: Where are you using your `MessageList` component? It almost looks like you're passing `MessageList` the component to `createStore`

Comment: Remove the last line from "MessageList" (`export default MessageList;`).

Comment: @RickJolly after remove that line it give that error : MessageList.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: t.map is not a function      .Line 16 is that: {messageList.map((messageForm, index) => <p key={index}>{messageForm} <button onClick={e => {

Comment: @azium I am using MessageList in existing project.It works.I imported it in other component:  import MessageList from 'components/chat/MessageList'; 
 <MessageList/>